# Ross, Joint distribution function with bounds on X and Y

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading  *Sheldon Ross: A First Course in Probability* and have a problem proving some property. I didn't find anything in the internet so will be grateful if somebody points me in the right direction. Here is the property:

$P(a_1 \lt X \le a_2, b_1 \lt Y \le b_2) = F(a_1, b_1) + F(a_2, b_2) - F(a_1, b_2) -F(a_2, b_1)$

Here is my start:

$P(a_1 \lt X \le a_2, b_1 \lt Y \le b_2) =P(\{a_1 \lt X \le a_2\} \cap \{b_1 \lt Y \le b_2\})$

$...=P(\{a_1 \lt X \le a_2\}) + P(\{b_1 \lt Y \le b_2\})-P(\{a_1 \lt X \le a_2\} \cup \{b_1 \lt Y \le b_2\})$

What are the next steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer can only be useful if you are familiar with expectations already.

$$\mathbf{1}_{a_{1}<X\leq a_{2}}\mathbf{1}_{b_{1}<Y\leq b_{2}}=$$$$\left(\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{2}}-\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{1}}\right)\left(\mathbf{1}_{Y\leq b_{2}}-\mathbf{1}_{Y\leq b_{1}}\right)=$$$$\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{2}}\mathbf{1}_{Y\leq b_{2}}-\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{1}}\mathbf{1}_{Y\leq b_{2}}-\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{2}}\mathbf{1}_{Y\leq b_{1}}+\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{1}}\mathbf{1}_{Y\leq b_{1}}=$$$$\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{2},Y\leq b_{2}}-\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{1},Y\leq b_{2}}-\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{2},Y\leq b_{1}}+\mathbf{1}_{X\leq a_{1},Y\leq b_{1}}$$

Taking the expectations on both sides results:$$P\left(a_{1}<X\leq a_{2},b_{1}<Y\leq b_{2}\right)=F\left(a_{2},b_{2}\right)-F\left(a_{1},b_{2}\right)-F\left(a_{2},b_{1}\right)+F\left(a_{1},b_{1}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you care explaining why expectation of characteristic function equals cdf?

Comment: In general $\int\mathbf1_A(x)dF_X(x)=P_X(A)=\mathbb P(X\in A)$. Applying that on $A=(-\infty,a]$ gives $\int\mathbf1_{(-\infty,a]}(x)=\mathbb P(X\in(-\infty,a]))=F_X(a)$. The LHS of this equation can also we written as $\mathbb E\mathbf1_{(-\infty,a]}(X)$ or, using a different notation, as $\mathbb E\mathbf1_{-\infty<X\leq a}$.

Comment: In an edit I made the notation a bit more simple. Forms like $\mathbf1_{-\infty X\leq a}$ are now written as $\mathbf1_{X\leq a}$. Further you speak in your comment of "characteristic function". I would rather choose for "indicator function". This because "characteristic function" can mean something else in probability theory.